# How to set localStorage item with JS and IMACROS?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, imacros

My code:

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL ("var title = document.getElementById(\"meta\").innerText; localStorage.setItem(\"title\", title);")
```

Imacros console output:

```
TypeError: result is undefined, line: 13
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem()` just updates `localStorage`, it doesn't return anything. That's what the message says.

Comment: @Barmar I don’t need return anything, I just need to set

Comment: You may want to check my Profile on how to ask Qt's about iMacros "a bit correctly"..., => FCI not mentioned, etc..., but `EVAL()` by Design is only "meant" for Data Manipulation and cannot interact with the DOM/Browser, but the `URL GOTO=javascript:xxx` Syntax can do that... :idea:

Comment: If you don't need to return anything, why are you trying to set a variable to the result of evaluating it?

Comment: Yeah, but @Barmar, the iMacros `EVAL()` Command is not the same as the JS `eval()`, more Info: https://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL // And like I already mentioned in my previous Comment, this is not the correct Command/Syntax to use anyway to implement the Func that #OP wants...

Comment: @chivracq I don't know IMacros, but I was talking about `SET !VAR2`

Comment: @Barmar, well this part was correct Syntax for the `EVA()` Command, ... which returns a String (Representation of a String/Number/Array) that needs to be stored in a Var (to be reused later in the Script).

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
// get text from div with #divid
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:divid EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}

// set text to localStorage 
SET !VAR2 EVAL ("localStorage.setItem('title', \"{{!VAR2}}\"); \"{{!VAR2}}\";")

// reset iMacros variables for later use
SET !VAR2 NULL
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

Comment: Nope, won't work, `EVAL()` won't know anything about `localStorage`, you should be getting some RuntimeError, ... unless you've enabled `!ERRORIGNORE`, and then the Statement won't do anything...